# Change formatting in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello i am currently running a function in my javascript called 'save' which has the functionality of:

```
function save(){

var oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('itemsArray')) || [];

var newItem = {};
var num = document.getElementById("num").value;

newItem[num] = {
    "methv": document.getElementById("methv").value
    ,'q1': document.getElementById("q1").value,
    'q2':document.getElementById("q2").value,
    'q3':document.getElementById("q3").value,
    'q4':document.getElementById("q4").value,
    'comm':document.getElementById("comm").value
};


oldItems.push(newItem);

localStorage.setItem('itemsArray', JSON.stringify(oldItems));
```

and currently the format of this comes out like this:

```
[{"1173627548":{"methv":"dont know","q1":"-","q2":"-","q3":"U","q4":"-","comm":""}}]
```

is there any way i can change this to a format to something like:

{1173627548,dont know, -,-,U,-,} 
Thanks

Comment: Of course you can write it like this but this wouldn't be JSON anymore. How would you parse it ?

Comment: So you want to strip the attribute names, structure and quotes? As dystroy mentioned, that's not JSON in the slightest, and you'll have trouble getting data back out of it if your format changes. Also you won't be able to write anything that has a comma in it without escaping somehow. If you want to do this, you might as well make your own function to write the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is use an array instead of an object:

```
newItem = [
    num,
    document.getElementById('methv').value,
    document.getElementById('q1').value,
    document.getElementById('q2').value,
    document.getElementById('q3').value,
    document.getElementById('q4').value,
    document.getElementById('comm').value
];
```